# multiply mangle -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning

Source: [Assembly Language Step by Step—Programming with Linux, 3rd Edition by Jeff Duntemann (2009)](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470497025,miniSiteCd-BSG.html)

Example:

> ...if you have a hex calculator, or a hex-capable screen calculator? The point is practice. Hexadecimal is the lingua franca of assemblers, to **multiply mangle** a metaphor. The more you burn a gut-level understanding of hex into your reflexes, the easier assembly language will be.

What is **multiply mangle** supposed to mean?

Comment: One thing that probably makes this more confusing is that this "multiply" is the adverb pronounced "multipl**ee**" rather than the verb pronounced "multipl**i**"!

Comment: Looks like a typo for "multipally" to me.  To multipally mangle a metaphor would be to mangle a metaphor in multiple ways.  The adverb form of the adjective "multiple" seems rare enough to escape many spell check dictionaries, including the one in my browser.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan - I don't think it's a typo; yes, "multipally" does occur in some books, but no dictionary I've checked even lists it as a word, and "multiply" does have an adverbial sense meaning "in multiple ways".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to multiply mangle = to mangle multiple times *( split infinitives aside )*

It means the author is **mangling** a metaphor in several different places in their use of the metaphor

> **The more** *( times )* **you do** *something* **the easier it gets.**

is the usual saying.

Comment: Still the example seems very odd. Could you add a reference?

Comment: Seriously? Never had a personal trainer in a gym?  Simple search on "the more you do the easier it gets" or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NrF5-0pwhxk)

Comment: I understand what it means. I meant an example using "multiply mangle".